# Refer to a lookup table that changes depending on data in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I am creating a tool which automatically inserts a date column which performs a vlookup, at the end of the exisiting data. 
The lookup table however can change every week so, I need to code within the tool to be able to work out the size of the look up table and refer to it in the formula.

Current code below.

```
Sub Macro1()

'Find how many rows and columns in each sheet

Set POCell1 = Sheets("PO").Range("A1")
Set toolCell1 = Sheets("tool").Range("A1")

PORowEndCell = Sheets("PO").Range(POCell1, POCell1.End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count
POColmEndCell = Sheets("PO").Range(POCell1, POCell1.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

toolRowEndCell = Sheets("tool").Range(toolCell1, ZSCell1.End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count
toolColmEndCell = Sheets("tool").Range(toolCell1, ZSCell1.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

'insert Title

Sheets("PO").Cells(1, PORowEndCell + 1).Value = "New Promised Date"

'Do Vlookup

For i = 1 To (POColmEndCell - 1)

Sheets("PO").Cells(i + 1, PORowEndCell + 1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(IF('PO'!RC4=VLOOKUP(RC3,'tool'!R2C3:R144C14,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(RC3,'tool'!R2C3:R144C14,11,FALSE),""""),"""")"

Next i

End Sub
```

Where the formula currently reads R144C14, 144 is calcuated by toolColmEndCell and 14 is calculated by toolRowEndCell. How do I get the vlookup to refer to these calculated variables as the final destination of the range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `&` to concatenate strings, so you do something like this

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(IF('PO'!RC4=VLOOKUP(RC3,'tool'!R2C3:R" & toolColmEndCell & "C" & toolRowEndCell & ",2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(RC3,'tool'!R2C3:R" & toolColmEndCell & "C" & toolRowEndCell & ",11,FALSE),""""),"""")"
```

If you only need the value and do not need to keep the formula in the cells, you can consider using `Application.Vlookup`